# Can javascript be used to delegate events to a native android application?

Tags: javascript, android

Is it possible to invoke a method or a function of a running android application using javascript?? OR Is there a possible way to communicate between Javascript and native android application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's such a method. Just use the `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()` method. It creates a javascript variable which is bound to a java object. You'll be able to call methods of this object from your javascript code.